# Navbar drop-down menu not working with Angular 1.6.1 and Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-3rd-party

I'm developing a web application with Angular 1.6.1 and Bootstrap 4 and I'm having problems with the nav menu bar dropdowns. but I don't know why drop-down menu doesn't work!

home.html

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
        <script src="../js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-3.0.6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
        <div ng-include="'../view/navbar.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
        <hr>
        <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

navbar.html

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" ><span class="brand"><h4>Test Data Identifier</h4></span></a>
    <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"  data-toggle="dropdown"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Subscription
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Agreement
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink2">
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link">l11</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link">l22</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link">l333</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have added all required libraries..

Comment: changed to angularjs because angular is for version 2+

Comment: you mean to say use angular 2?

Comment: No. You tagged the question as [tag:angular] which is not correct. You should have tagged it with [tag:angularjs] because your question is about angularjs version 1.x. Stefan fixed it for you.

Comment: @Igor exactly.  if it has the wrong tag, the people who can answer it wont find it

Comment: How do you know you have added all the required libraries? You have added `ui.bootstrap` as an AngularJS module but there are no ui-bootstrap directives in the HTML. What about `ngSanitize` and `ngAnimate`?

Comment: This have added  "You have added ui.bootstrap as an AngularJS module but there are no ui-bootstrap directives in the HTML", is it necessary to  ngSanitize and ngAnimate